# The meaning of "smiling over her shoulder"

Tags: idioms

https://genius.com/James-arthur-say-you-wont-let-go-lyrics

> [Verse 1] I met you in the dark
>
> You lit me up
>
> You made me feel as though
>
> I was enough
>
> We danced the night away
>
> We drank too much
>
> I held your hair back when
>
> You were throwing up
>
> [Pre-Chorus] Then **you smiled over your shoulder**
>
> For a minute, I was stone cold sober
>
> I pulled you closer to my chest
>
> And you asked me to stay over
>
> I said, I already told ya
>
> I think that you should get some rest

We have "look over your shoulder" but I could not find the exact meaning of "smile over your shoulder".

Does it mean the girl is walking away from you , stopping for a moment , turning his head , looking at you and then smiling?

Comment: I think it means he was standing behind her and then she turned a little bit and smiled over her shoulder. You can find a lot of images in Google for "smiling over shoulder".

Answer (score 1):

Smile over one's shoulder means what you suggest. While lyrics are usually a bad source of normal English, in this case it means "you looked over your shoulder and smiled". Note that the girl has just been "throwing up" and the singer is, therefore, standing behind her and holding her hair to stop the vomit from making it dirty.